# NVARCHAR(MAX) & Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

A friend has created a few tables for me and used `nvarchar(max)` on around four of the columns in the table. Inserts and Updates are handled using stored procedures.

Am I right to worry that executing the stored procedures will error if one or more of the columns reach the MAX limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max limit is 2GB(1 billion unicode characters) so unless you push in a billion characters per columns you are fine, otherwise yes you will get an error

probably

Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1

String or binary data would be truncated.

Same will happen if you do this

```
create table #test(id varchar(4))

insert into #test values('12345')
```